# Twilio not sending SMS inside firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, twilio

i am trying to send sms using twilio api for node.js through a firebase cloud function but the sms is not sent. however if the same code i run as an independent java script code, then it works fine.can someone 
 please help why this is not happening inside the firebase cloud function. the code is attached below:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.sendNotfication = functions.database.ref('/kakuh/{pushId}/firstName')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const original = snapshot.val();
      const accountSid = 'ACb6b4820df073e63312382f95b0314d07';
      const authTcoken = 'c60923ca097368662b39dfab470f2fd1';
      const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
      client.messages
      .create({
          from: '+16304263296',
          body: original,
          to: '+918169813384'
        });

      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('firstName').set(uppercase);
    });
```

Comment: I don't see how you're checking for errors with the Twilio API.  The call could be failing.  Also, it doesn't seem that you're waiting for the call to Twilio to finish asynchronously, which means it might not ever complete.  You need to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the reply. if i run just the twilio code then it works fine but when called inside firebase function its not working. the code which is working is below:const accountSid = 'ACb6b4820df073e63312382f95b0314d07';
      const authTcoken = 'c60923ca097368662b39dfab470f2fd1';
      const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
      client.messages
      .create({
          from: '+16304263296',
          body: original,
          to: '+918169813384'
        });

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wait for Twilio to respond, `then` `return` to Firebase.

Try this:

---

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotfication = functions.database.ref('/kakuh/{pushId}/firstName')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        const original = snapshot.val();
        const accountSid = 'ACb6b4820df073e63312382f95b0314d07';
        const authToken = 'c60923ca097368662b39dfab470f2fd1';
        const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

        client.messages
            .create({
                from: '+16304263296',
                body: original,
                to: '+918169813384'
            })
            .then((message) => {
                console.log(message.sid);
                console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
                const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
                return snapshot.ref.parent.child('firstName').set(uppercase);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                throw (err);
            });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the response and modified code. I am still getting an error which is below:  error: Cannot find module 'twilio'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at exports.sendNotfication.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/srv/index.js:53:24)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>

Comment: Use the `npm install twilio` command in the folder containing your Cloud Function. Then, check `package.json` for something like `"twilio": "^3.32.0"`. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies)